# Range validation not working properly in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I am generating data validation javascript in an Asp.Net MVC 3 application with the following code

```
[DisplayName("Latitude Degrees")]
[Range(0, 90, ErrorMessage = "Latitude degrees must be between {1} and {2}")]
public Int32? LatitudeDegrees { get; set; }
```

on a view model. When it was MVC2 this worked just fine, if I entered a value outside of 0-90 in the textbox I got the validation warnings.

Since I moved the application to MVC 3, whenever I put any value into the texbox, legal or illegal I get the validation error appear next to it.

I have EnableClientValidation set to true and UseUnobtrusiveJavascript is off (nothing in web.config or the views to turn it on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want unobtrusive client side validation in web config try setting both `ClientValidationEnabled` and `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` to true. Then make sure you have removed all traces of `MicrosoftAjax*` client script libraries and have included jquery and jquery.validate as that's what MVC 3 uses:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I needed to turn on the unobtrusive JS, it all works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I coudln't reproduce your problem! I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 with ClientValidationEnabled set to true and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled set to false, and I've tried the same attributes (copy-pasted them, actually), and everything seems to work just as expected. The problem might be somewhere else other than what you've listed here.